# I lost my wordpress admin password

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, authentication, admin

I lost the password for my wordpress admin, and tried this md5 generator:

```
http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/
```

and I used `testing` as my login which I put through the above page's md5 generator, and copied that into my wp database table "`wp_users`" into the user pass field. Although I still couldn't login to my wp admin. But if I use the lost password feature in the admin login section it redirects to a landing page saying site is still "under construction".

What should I do next?

Comment: Does wordpress really use md5?I doubt it

Comment: Enn... try open up another wordpress production and copy back the password field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if your website is live you can use 
http://domain.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword to send a recovery email. If its not live then you can use this command in your PHPMYADMIN

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5('newpassword') WHERE user_login = "admin";
```

You can also use PHPMYSQL's gui to get a new password. Goto wp_users table and edit your row. Then add your new password in the password box (without encryption), and select MD5 from the password field type dropdown. It will automatically encrypt it.

Comment: Do they really not salt it? That's mildly horrifying...

Comment: Yes wordpress uses hashes and salt. But it has this feature for this exact situtation where someone forgets their password. You can reset the password without any salts or hashes. but once you login through the password, it will automatically salts it and save it to the database.

Comment: ok this did not work, my wp login is:  username: Admin, password: newpassword

Comment: did you use the command or gui?

Comment: Try replacing 'admin' with 'Admin'

Comment: and i did this trhough phpmyadmin