# How can I reset my WordPress admin password?

Tags: wordpress

I lost my wp-admin password and I have no access to the email I used to register my WordPress. I have access to the host where I used softaculous app installer.
I have tried editing the details by putting another admin username and password but unfortunately I can't access the wp dashboard with all the features like plugins and so on.

Comment: Any of these answers help? [Wordpress solution](https://wordpress.org/support/article/resetting-your-password/)? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665078/15040627)? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29720961/15040627)? Downvotes are not mine!

Comment: Do you still have access to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. go to your.site/wp-login.php, click "Lost your password?" And reset your password by email.

OR

2. Go to phpMyAdmin -> your-site-db -> wp_users table, select your user, click "edit", in password field select MD5 type of field, enter new value in field, save.

Comment: Thanks .It has worked out.

Answer (score 0):

By clicking "Lost your password?" And reset your password by email
See this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RQg3.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Actually I had lost access to the email so this couldn't help me